# How can I optimise math operations in this method?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

```
public static BitArray ShLo(BitArray B)
{
    return new BitArray(System.BitConverter.GetBytes(Math.Floor((GetIntFromBitArray(B)/2) % (Math.Pow(2, 64)) )));
}
private static ulong GetIntFromBitArray(BitArray bitArray)
{
    var array = new int[2];
    bitArray.CopyTo(array, 0);
    return (uint)array[0] + ((ulong)(uint)array[1] << 32);
}
```

This method takes a long time. Can I optimize it?

Comment: Split it into separate statements and get a decent profiler to see _which_ part takes "a long time".  Until you do that you're just guessing.

Comment: What is your method actually trying to achieve? It doesn't help that we don't know what `GetIntFromBitArray` does...

Comment: @JonSkeet update code. Now GetIntFromBitArray method here.

Comment: But still no description of what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: @JonSkeet In this method BitArray converting to Integer. It's for cryptographic algorithm hashing.

Comment: `ShLo` is not a very descriptive name. What is this method supposed to do? What sort of input (number of bits) does it need to handle? Do you need to create a new `BitArray` or can you reuse an existing one? Do you need to use `BitArray`s?

Comment: "BitArray converting to integer" is far from a clear description of what you're trying to do. I would say that implementing your own cryptographic algorithm is rarely a good idea, and definitely not using `BitArray`...

Comment: @PieterWitvoet ShLo is operation from standart.ShLo(u) for u ∈ {0, 1}^(8n) it's word ⟨⌊u/ 2⌋⟩_(8n). It's hard to explain in few words.

Comment: @JonSkeet what is the best way to write it?

Comment: I suspect just manipulating a byte array will be the most efficient approach... But ideally, use an existing rigourously tested implementation.

Comment: Using % and pow for bit masking is a crime. Use bitwise arithmetic and precomputed masks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a good speed up by changing the mod 2^64 to a bit and operation:

```
public static BitArray ShLo(BitArray B)
{
    return new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(Math.Floor((double)((GetIntFromBitArray(B)/2) & Int64.MaxValue))));
}
```

I would echo what has been said in the comments, which is it looks like you want [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) which will allow you to do math and bit level operations on arbitrary sized integers.

Comment: Excellent! It's really speed up my code. And now worst place - GetIntFromBitArray  method.

Comment: Except it was wrong :( I said bit shift, I was confused, it should be zeroing everything but the back 64 bytes. The code is updated.

Comment: even if my BitArray B have a length 64?
`BitArray B = new BitArray(64);`